# How to change language?

Tags: android, localization

I have a published build in alpha stage at google play store.

When I download it and change language I need to kill the app and open again to reflect the language changes.

I want immediate changes.

How can I do that?

Comment: you need make two languagefor instance russian and english and you have to make separate xml file for each respective language and you have to write all translations in the xml folder

Comment: I already done that

Comment: Can you show how do you manage language change? Because the configuration changes, it is impossible to reflect language changes without recreating the app. But you can put transition animation for recreation process

Comment: should be related with https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Comment: may be helpful for you: https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your activity .

```
 val intent = this.intent//this will get current activity intent
 this.finish() // this will finish current activity
 startActivity(intent) // And this will apply changes and restart activity
```

Comment: restarting activity can be done just by calling `recreate();` inside an activity.

Comment: that's  true but what we will if i have pass data to this activity?. For example last fragment name or number

Comment: in that case your approach should be used. I suggested recreate in case of this question only, since there is no data to pass.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create two string file for both languages.. just assume you have two languages to select 1.English 2.Russian..  For English Int i=1 and for Russian Int i=2;
if you select English then store the value of I in SharedPrefrence .. when you re-open app...first check the values of I. if I is 1 then set Language to English if I is 2 set language to Russian..so you don't have to choose language everytime when you open your app